# Problems configuring duration of FreeRTOS timer tick

Tags: c, avr, freertos

I decided to try FreeRTOS with Arduino Uno (ATmega 328p) and blink a led from timer hook. However, it seems that I've set timers in FreeRTOS wrong, and cannot find the error. I thought that the LED will go on/off every 1 second (frequency of 1 kHz and counter limit of 1000), but it is ~14 sec. What can be wrong?

Here's my main.c

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"

#define hookTICK_CALLS_BEFORE_POST    ( 1000 )

void vApplicationTickHook( void );

static uint16_t uxCallCounter = 0;
void vApplicationTickHook( void ){
    uxCallCounter++;
    if( uxCallCounter >= hookTICK_CALLS_BEFORE_POST ){
        uxCallCounter = 0;
        PORTD ^= 1 << 2;
    }
}   


int main(void)
{
    DDRD |= 1 << 2;
    /* Replace with your application code */
    vTaskStartScheduler();
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Here's FreeRTOSConfig.h

```
#define configUSE_PREEMPTION        1
#define configUSE_IDLE_HOOK         0
#define configUSE_TICK_HOOK         1
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ          ( ( unsigned long ) 8000000 ) /*According to fuses, 0xFF 0xDA 0xFD mean using external oscillator at 16MHz with internal set to 8MHz */
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ          ( (portTickType ) 1000 )
#define configMAX_PRIORITIES        ( 4 )
#define configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE    ( ( unsigned short ) 85 )
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE       ( (size_t ) ( 1500 ) )
#define configMAX_TASK_NAME_LEN     ( 8 )
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY    0
#define configUSE_16_BIT_TICKS      1
#define configIDLE_SHOULD_YIELD     0
#define configQUEUE_REGISTRY_SIZE   0

/* Co-routine definitions. */
#define configUSE_CO_ROUTINES       0
#define configMAX_CO_ROUTINE_PRIORITIES ( 2 )

/* Set the following definitions to 1 to include the API function, or zero
to exclude the API function. */

#define INCLUDE_vTaskPrioritySet        0
#define INCLUDE_uxTaskPriorityGet       0
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelete             1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskCleanUpResources   0
#define INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend            0
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelayUntil         1
#define INCLUDE_vTaskDelay              1
```

Build options (Atmel studio 7)

```
-x c -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.6.364\include" -I"../FreeRTOS" -I"../FreeRTOS/Source/include" -I"../FreeRTOS/Source/Portable/Thirdparty/GCC/ATmega"  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.6.364\gcc\dev\atmega328p" -c -std=gnu99 -MD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.o)"
```

Comment: You're _not_ showing the initialization code, so we don't know _what_ frequency you're actually setting the tick to [and what tick frequency you want]. Obviously, it's 14x less frequent that you think it is. In lieu of fixing that, how about (e.g.): `#define hookTICK_CALLS_BEFORE_POST    ( 1000 / 14 )`

Comment: freeRTOS & 2k uC makes not too much sense. IMO buy STM32 Nucleo board and start with freeRTOS on ARM Cortex machines

Comment: I use AVR for debug: I just better know avr assembler, so I can more easily trace compiler optimizations. So I can be more sure that I didn't mess up with const/static/volatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some AVRs use watchdog timer as tick source (see atmega328pb example) while others use Timer0 (see atmega323 example). It depends on if the MCU has Enhanced WDT with interrupt capability. The details are provided in FreeRTOS\Source\portable\ThirdParty\GCC\ATmega\portmacro.h line 89 FreeRTOS\Source\portable\ThirdParty\GCC\ATmega\port.c line 46 and FreeRTOS\Source\portable\ThirdParty\GCC\ATmega\readme.md

If WDT is used, timer tick frequency is configured in portmacro.h (default is 15ms, so is the smallest period) and is not influenced by configTICK_RATE_HZ value. To switch to TIMER0 (preconfigured) just replace the strings #if defined(WDIE) && defined(WDIF) ... #endif with #define portUSE_TIMER0 . Using -DportUSE_TIMER0 -UportUSE_WDTO as global compiler keys doesn't work. You can use some other timer, see port.c and forth on how Timer0 is configured.

When I switched to Timer0 as described above, and made changes in FreeRTOSConfig.h

```
#define configCPU_CLOCK_HZ          ( ( unsigned long ) 16000000 )
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ          ( ( TickType_t ) 1000 )
```

and made uxCallCounter volatile in main.c, I got the behavior I wanted. Tick error is <5% (for `#define hookTICK_CALLS_BEFORE_POST ( 50000 )` tick period is 47.9s) that matches external oscillator documentation.